# Why wont Minecraft let me break blocks or use my inventory

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been playing Minecraft for about a month. I got on one day and it wouldn't let me break blocks or use my inventory. I'm playing on the mod pack "Yogbox" and I'm on survival with no cheats.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Arqade! As it stands, it will be very hard to answer your question. Can you give a bit more detail? Are there any errors? Can you see your hotbar on the bottom of the screen? Does anything else look odd or out of the ordinary? Is this only on one world, or on all of them?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the details you gave us, I'm assumimg you are in Adventure Mode (you may have used NEI or TMI to switch gamemodes).

The proper way to fix this is to switch gamemodes with NEI/TMI until you can break blocks while not being in creative.